# Is .thenValue() blocking?

Tags: c++, future, folly

In a lot of places I find something like :

```
std::move(A).thenValue(B)
```

Is thenValue() blocking on the future "A". I read through Folly documentation but couldn't understand it.
https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/docs/Futures.md

Comment: I'm not familiar with Folly, but, how could it not block? What would you get if it didn't block?

Comment: The paragraph at the start says that it attaches a callback. I can't see why that would block, especially since the code snippet seems to suggest that it returns a second `Future`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not blocking.  Conceptually, you can think of the signature like this (though this is not the actual signature):

```
template <typename T>
template <typename TResult>
Future<TResult> Future<T>::thenValue(std::function<TResult(T&&)> callback) { ... }
```

The basic idea is that if the future represented by `std::move(A)` succeeds, the passed callback (`B`) will be executed, passing in the value that the `A` future produced.  The callback's return value becomes the result of the future returned by `thenValue()`.

If you're a visual person (like me) then perhaps labeling parts of the signature will help:

```
template <typename T>
template <typename TResult>
Future<TResult> Future<T>::thenValue(std::function<TResult(T&&)> callback) { ... }
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^                                        ^^^^^^^^
       3            1                                                2
```

1. The future you are invoking `thenValue` on.
2. The callback function you pass to `thenValue`.
3. The future returned by `thenValue`.

When (1) has a successful result, (2) is invoked with that result.  When (2) returns, (3) produces the return value of (2).

The future (3) is constructed synchronously, but the callback (2) is invoked asynchronously.